# R2 Score in BigQueryML

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, statistics, xgboost

Generally, in statistics, the R² Score is between 0 and 1. But, it can be negative in BigQuery ML training results using [`XGBoost(model type = BOOSTED_TREE_REGRESSOR)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-boosted-tree#create_model_statement_for_boosted_tree_models_using_xgboost).

So, what is the coefficient of determination R² in the evaluation of models in BigQuery ML?

Comment: R2 scores can be negative also . See [What does negative R-squared mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183265/what-does-negative-r-squared-mean) , [When is R squared negative?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183265/what-does-negative-r-squared-mean). [BigQuery ML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/introduction) does not have its own methodology to evaluate models, it also follows the same basic statistics. You can find more articles/post regarding negative R2 if you search on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

R2 score can be negative. R2 is not always the square of anything, so it can have a negative value without violating any rules of math. R2 is negative only when the chosen model does not follow the trend of the data.